# Android: Passing Date in putExtra

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm launching an activity and would like to pass a `Date(Time)` value to it. I've passed all my other parameters with `i.putExtra("noteName", "Hello World")` but I'm clueless on how to pass the date value and then retrieve it as a date with `getExtra()`.

I can easily use `i.putExtra("noteDate",noteDate);`

but then how do i retrieve it in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()`; I don't see an `extras.getDate()` ?

Should I convert it to `Float` and then back (in the `Activity`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've simply used

```
i.putExtra("noteDate",myDate);
```

and then on the activity I used:

```
Date dt = new Date(extras.getString("noteDate"));
```

and it works like a charm!? Is this dangerous? To assume the date will always be parsed correctly on all devices?

Comment: this is deprecated now. So better to use date.getTime() and date.setTime().

Answer (score 49):

Use `date.getTime()` and `date.setTime()` and transfer it as a Long.

```
i.putExtra("date", date.getTime());

Date d = new Date();
d.setTime(i.getLongExtra("date", -1));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having trouble with this, my date returns 1 Jan 1970 no matter what I do.

Comment: check to see what i.getLongExtra() is returning, it returns a -1 if "date" is not in the extras.

Comment: yes It's -1, but if I do a i.putExtra("noteDate", noteDate.toString()); I can extras.getString("noteDate")); and the value comes through. If I put it as a date and use getIntent.getLongExtra("noteDate",-1)) i get back -1 ?

Answer (score 4):

better convert into a `long`, use `putExtra(String name, long value)` and recreate then back in the new `Activity`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to java, could you explain how to do Date > Long and back?

Comment: long millis = [date.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()); <--> Date date = [new Date(millis)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long));

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
i.putExtra("date", date.getTime());
Date d = new Date();
d.setTime(i.getLongExtra("date", -1));
```

USE : if you are using Calendar instead of Date to get the long value

```
i.putExtra("date", date.getTime().getTime); 
Date d = new Date();
d.setTime(i.getLongExtra("date", -1));
```