# How to Pass Current Date from One activity to next activity in android only using click event and intent

Tags: android, android-intent

How to Pass Current Date from One activity to next activity(Pass the current date to the soap services) in android
only using click event and intent.....

Comment: try this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382081/android-passing-date-in-putexra

Answer (score 1):

```
From the current activity:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("date", dateObj.getTime());
startActivity(intent);
From next activity:

Date dateObj = new Date(getIntent().getExtras().getLongExtra("date", -1));
```

You should pass the time as a long value and convert it back on the other activity to avoid date parsing from string issues on different devices.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getCurrentDate() {

    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    time.month = time.month + 1;

    String date = String.valueOf(time.year) + "-"
            + String.valueOf(time.month) + "-"
            + String.valueOf(time.monthDay);
    return date;
}
```

in your onClick Listener Add This Code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("date", getCurrentDate());
startActivity(intent);
```

In Your Next Activity's onCreate() Add This Code.

```
String date=getIntent().getStringExtra("date");

You can parse this date into Date object
```